# Regex to validate Unique Transaction Identifier

Tags: regex, uti, unique-transaction-identifier

I'm trying to write a regex pattern to validate Unique Transaction Identifiers (UTI). See description: [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_Transaction_Identifier)

The UTI consists of two concatenated parts, the prefix and the transaction identifier. Here is a summary of the rules I'm trying to take into account:

- The prefix is exactly 10 alphanumeric characters.
- The transaction identifier is 1-32 characters long.
- The transaction identifier is alphanumeric, however the following special characters are also allowed: `. : _ -`
- The special characters can not appear at the beginning or end of the transaction identifier.
- It is not allowed to have two special characters in a row.

I have so far constructed a pattern to validate the UTI for the first 4 of these points (matched with ignored casing):

```
^[A-Z0-9]{11}((\w|[:\.-]){0,30}[A-Z0-9])?$
```

However I'm struggling with the last point (no two special characters in a row). I readily admit to being a bit of a novice when it comes to regex and I was thinking there might be some more advanced technique that I'm not familiar with to accomplish this. Any regex gurus out there care to enlighten me?

---

**Solved**: Thanks to user Bohemian for helping me find the pattern I was looking for. My final solution looks like this:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]{11}((?!.*[.:_-]{2})[a-zA-Z0-9.:_-]{0,30}[a-zA-Z0-9])?$
```

I will leave the question open for follow-up answers in case anyone has any further suggestions for improvements.

Comment: Your regex suggests that letters must be uppercase. Is that true? Lowercase letters are "alphanumeric" too.

Comment: @Bohemian: Yes, I'm actually running the matching engine with ignored casing enabled, I made a small remark about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
^[A-Z0-9]{11}(?!.*[.:_-]{2})[A-Z0-9.:_-]{0,30}[A-Z0-9]$
```

The secret sauce is the negative look ahead `(?!.*[.:_-]{2})`, which *asserts* (without consuming input) that the following text does *not* contain 2 consecutive "special" chars `.:_-`.

---

Note that your attempt, which uses `\w`, allows lowercase letters and underscores too, because
`\w` is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for! I made a minor adjustment, posting my final solution in an edit above.